# SQL..Sum two rows

Tags: mysql, sum

Sample data:

```
LOCATION   NAME   LABEL1   LABEL2 SERVICE TIME
NY         Andrew    A       B      HOUSE  2555
NY         Andrew    A       B      CAR    35
NJ         Copley    C       A      HOUSE  1025
NY         Copley    A       B      HOUSE  650
VA         Dalton    D       C      PET    25
```

What I want to do is add another column where in it shows sum(Time) of rows with same data except for the Service.Also, the services that I need are only the sum of car and house.Is this possible? If not can you help me with the right query

Sample output I need:

```
LOCATION   NAME   LABEL1   LABEL2 SERVICE TIME     SUM
NY         Andrew    A       B      HOUSE  2555    **2590**
NY         Andrew    A       B      CAR    35
NJ         Copley    C       A      HOUSE  1025    1025
NY         Copley    A       B      HOUSE  650     650
```

Comment: Your tables are not normalised. Normalising them would make this really easy, get rid of your data duplication, and just be all-round the proper thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `LOCATION`, `NAME`, `LABEL1`, `LABEL2`, SUM(`TIME`)
  FROM `myTable`
 WHERE `SERVICE` = "CAR" OR `SERVICE` = "HOUSE"
 GROUP BY `LOCATION`, `NAME`, `LABEL1`, `LABEL2`
```

This does not add another column, but it does return the data you requested in a resultset when run as a query. I recommend taking this approach.

You should also ensure that your [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) are set up optimally for this sort of query.

Comment: Note that you could create a view using this `SELECT` if you want to easily run other queries which include the `SUM`.

Comment: Is using WHERE `SERVICE` = "CAR" OR `SERVICE` = "HOUSE" the same as WHERE 'SERVICE' IN('CAR','HOUSE') ?

Comment: @Cha: Yes, and that would be nicer actually.

Comment: how would I make the time of the CAR and HOUSE add up?they still don't add up, it returns two different rows even though all details are the same, well, except for the service. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cha: That's what the query in my answer does.

Comment: I tried it but it does not give me the sum of house and car. I don't know how to explain what I need clearly. When I run it the sum column is the same with time column

Comment: @Cha: Well, that's not what is supposed to happen. I don't know what else to say, really; without access to your database I can't see for myself.

Comment: I got it..thanks you were right, I forgot to remove the 'SERVICE" in group by that is why it didn't add up. THANK YOU for your help!